# Users change own event registration

Tags: civievent, registration

I have events that i would like to have users able to update their registration. Mostly i want them to be able to cancel. These are free events so no refund is needed. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: which CMS are you using? Webforms is a possible solution if you're on Drupal.

Comment: i am using Drupal. I tried using webforms for this but it seems like a very difficult solution.